# Custom checkbox don't work on Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, checkbox, font-awesome

I custom my checkbox with FontAwesome but it's work only on Chrome...

I put this on my page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_cd" class="custom-checkbox" />
```

Here my css:

```
/*
input.custom-checkbox {
    visibility: hidden;
}
*/
input.custom-checkbox:checked::after, input.custom-checkbox::after {
    visibility: visible;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}

input.custom-checkbox:checked::after {
  content: '\f058';
  color: #16A085;
}

input.custom-checkbox::after {
  content: '\f057';
  color: #C0392B;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZKS/7h3bqxot/)

Thanks,

Comment: You can't use the `::after` of a checkbox. Use a `<label>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, sadly ::after it's not supported on Firefox..

Comment: Not just Firefox. It doesn't work on _any_ browser that is standards-compliant. That it works on Chrome is a fluke!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In firefox, ::before or ::after wont work on input. You need to work with the label instead of the input.

Lets work with these-

```
input.custom-checkbox + label::before
input.custom-checkbox:checked + label::after
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<i>` tag with Font Awesome instead of css property and then describe the behavior that you want in jQuery. For example:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_cd" class="custom-checkbox" />
<i id="check"  class="fa fa-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**CSS:**

```
i {cursor:pointer;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( "#check" ).click(function() {
    if ($("#checkbox_cd").is(':checked')){
        $( "#check" ).removeClass( "fa-check-circle-o");
        $( "#check" ).addClass( "fa-times" );
        $( "#checkbox_cd").prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $( "#check" ).removeClass( "fa-times" );
        $( "#check" ).addClass( "fa-check-circle-o" );
        $( "#checkbox_cd").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7h3bqxot/1/)

P.S: if you want to hide the initial checkbox just put this:

**CSS:**

```
#checkbox_cd {display:none;}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed, It's an alternative ! Thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mr Lister and Mokarram Khan, I wanted with css only, I use label and it works !

Here my checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_cd" class="custom-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox_cd"></label>
```

And my CSS:

```
input.custom-checkbox {
    visibility: hidden;
}

input.custom-checkbox:checked + label::after, input.custom-checkbox + label::after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 60px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

input.custom-checkbox:checked +label::after {
    content: '\f058';
    color: #16A085;
}

input.custom-checkbox + label::after {
  content: '\f057';
  color: #C0392B;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have just done

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```